# python visual studio code pip cmdlet error cant install

Tags: python, pip

hey i have been trying to code in python using visual studio code and i have been trying to download modules (numpy) using pip but i keep facing this error
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

i have pip installed my desktop but the error persist. Any suggestions or alternatives would be appreciated! Have a nice day

Comment: Try using `pip3` instead of `pip`